# Xamarin - After updating to current 5.9 (431) creating ActivityElement (current MonoTouch.Dialog) fails

Tags: xamarin, monotouch.dialog

knFollowing code will result in an NULL exception, after updating the Xamarin environment and recompiling the whole code.

Here is a code fragment:

```
public override void ViewDidLoad ()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad ();

    //Test beginning
    ActivityElement element = new ActivityElement ();
    if (element == null)
        Console.WriteLine ("element == null");  
    element.Animating = true;
    //Test ending

    Section section = new Section ("Connecting...".t()) {
      new ActivityElement() {Animating = true} 
    };
```

I added the test section, because of the error on assigning true to element.Animating.

Debugging this code: Every member of element is after the "new ActivityElement" creation NULL, so assigning true to element.Animating results in an error, but element itself is not NULL.

I don't know why. Why are the member NULL? The whole app runs without any problem.
Any suggestion?

Thx a lot!

Comment: Can you describe your setup with the versions of the libraries (iOS and/or Android) and have a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.  Something like this will be difficult to diagnose without more information.

Comment: Its an iOS app (minimum 8.0).

Comment: I can reproduce it with a clean project, if this is code that was working and is now broken I recommend going to the Xamarin forums and uploading a minimal example and getting their engineers to look at it.

Comment: I sended the problem to xamarin-support and now they work on it. Thx for the help, i will comment later, if there is any result.